# MSAL JS throws multiple_matching_tokens_detected exception while renewing id token using acquireTokenSilent function

Tags: javascript, reactjs, authentication, azure-ad-msal, msal.js

I'm using [MSAL](https://github.com/AzureAD/microsoft-authentication-library-for-js) for authentication in a react app. I'm using localStorage as caching storage for the UserAgentApplication instance. The loginPopup method provides an idToken which is valid for an hour. For the purpose of my application, I want to refresh this idToken silently when it is expired. As per all the documentations, acquireTokenSilent function will automatically refresh the token if it's expired otherwise the cached token will be provided if the client id is passed as scope parameter.

However, I'm getting following exception upon calling acquireTokenSilent function.

```
The cache contains multiple tokens satisfying the requirements. Call AcquireToken again providing more requirements like authority|multiple_matching_tokens_detected
```

Surprisingly this exception is thrown on chrome but not on edge browser. Is there any browser specific caching stored in file system? I've cleared the cookies and local storage data in chrome but nothing helped.

Here are some responsible code snippets:

```
login = () => {
return this.app.loginPopup(this.applicationConfig.graphScopes).then(
  idToken => {
    return idToken;
  },
  () => {
    return null;
  }
);
```

};

```
getToken = () => {
return this.app
  .acquireTokenSilent([this.applicationConfig.clientID], '', this.app.getUser())
  .then(
    idToken => {
      return idToken;
    },
    error => {
      console.log(
        "Error occured while loading silent token. Error - ",
        error
      );
    }
  );
```

};

First I try to call the getToken function and if token is not found then I'm redirecting user to the login page where the login function is used. Please note that I'm working with idToken in both cases but not accessToken.

Any help is much appreciated to make this work in chrome.

Answer (score 1):

Try this code i think It's work for you.

```
import { MsalService } from "@azure/msal-angular";

        msalConfig = {
            auth: {
                clientId: 'Your Client Id Here', //This is your client ID,
                authority: "https://login.microsoftonline.com/common", //This is your tenant info
            },
            cache: {
                cacheLocation: "localStorage",
                storeAuthStateInCookie: true
            }
        };
        myMSALObj = new Msal.UserAgentApplication(this.msalConfig);

        let requestObj = { scopes: ["user.read"] }
        let obj = this.myMSALObj;
        obj.loginPopup(requestObj).then(function (loginResponse) {
            obj.acquireTokenSilent(requestObj)
                .then(function (tokenResponse) {
                    console.log(tokenResponse.accessToken);
                    callmicrosoftLogin(tokenResponse.accessToken)
                }).catch(function (error) {
                    console.log(error);
                })
            obj.acquireTokenPopup(requestObj)
                .then(function (tokenResponse) {
                    console.log(tokenResponse.accessToken)
                }).catch(function (err) {
                    console.log(err);
                })
        }).catch(function (error) {
            console.log(error);
        });
```

Comment: I'm using version MSAL 0.2.4 so this code will not fit. Do you think updating the version will solve the problem? Also I'm working with idToken not the accessToken

Comment: I think the updated MSAL version will help you. i am using access token instead of idToken because in my Angular application I am calling Microsoft Graph API for User Details Using that Access Token as backend verfication.

Comment: Great. I was reading the documentation that the responses in the updated version also consists of idToken. I'll give it a try and I'll get back to you. Thanks for your response.

Comment: Thank you, Vishal. Updating to the latest version has solved my problem.